# Haskell, Local definition and variables, confused :/

Tags: haskell

```
f0 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
        f0 a b c = x a b - x a c - x b c
           where x b a = a + b
```

Can someone explain me how the functions knows what to do when it gets to the...

```
    where x b a = a + b
```

... statement? Does it just translate to something like this?

```
f0 a b c = (a + b) a b - (a + b) a c - (a + b) b c
```

Comment: ah, or is it just that the "h" is just another functions which takes two variables and add them so
f0 0 0 1 = x a b - x a c - x b c
    where x b a = a + b

is just something like:  0+0 - 0+1 - 0+1 = -2 ?

Comment: Exactly. `x b a = a + b` is a function definition (that happens to have local scope). `f0 0 0 1 = x 0 0 - x 0 1 - x 0 1`.

Comment: Also note that the variables `a,b` in `x a b = b + a` shadow the other variables `a,b` defined in `f0 a b c = ..`. I would recommend to rename them to avoid confusion between different variables with the same name, say `... where x v w = w + v`. Turning on warnings would also spot this shadowing issue.

Comment: “Does it just translate to something like this? […]”—Close, it translates to `f0 a b c = (\ b a -> a + b) a b - (\ b a -> a + b) a c - (\ b a -> a + b) b c`, or more simply `(b + a) - (c + a) - (c + b)`. `x` is a local function equivalent to `flip (+)`, which of course is equivalent to `(+)`, since addition of integers is commutative. This is slightly awkward because it reuses the names `a` and `b`, *shadowing* the parameters of `f0`, which generates a warning if you enable `-Wall`; an (alpha-)equivalent definition would be `x m n = n + m`.

Answer (score 4):

> > [...] or is it just that the "x" is just another functions which takes two variables and add them [...]
>
> Exactly. `x b a = a + b` is a function definition (that happens to have local scope). `f0 0 0 1 = x 0 0 - x 0 1 - x 0 1`. – [duplode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53467046/haskell-local-definition-and-variables-confused#comment93804866_53467046)

Answer (score 0):

In some other pseudo language this will look like this.

```
int function fo(int a, int b, int c){
  int function x(int a, int b){
     return a + b;
  }
  return x(a,b) - x(a,c) - x(b,c)
}
```

The way you have put it as a question,

> f0 a b c = (a + b) a b - (a + b) a c - (a + b) b c

it looks like inline substitution like C macros. It is not simple code substitution. It is more like inline function. X is a function which gets called.